# Can I re-run a Power Automate flow instance from history?

Tags: powershell, power-automate

Is there any way to find and re-run an earlier instance of a Power Automate workflow programmatically?

I can do this manually: download the .csv file containing the instances, search in the `Trigger output` column the one I want, get the id, copy-paste the run URL, and click resubmit.

I tried with Power Automate itself:
The built-in Flow Management connector supports only to find a specific flow by name, and does not even go to the history.

**PowerShell**:
Installed the PowerApps module, I can list the instances with

```
Get-FlowRun -FlowName {flow name}
```

But I don't see the same properties as in the exported .csv file, and there's also no `Run-Flow` command that would let me run it.

So, I am a little stuck here; could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot programmatically resubmit the Flow run from the history with PowerShell or by any other api method yet.

But can avoid some manual work by using `workflow` function in a Flow `compose` step, we can automate the composition of Flow history run url. [Read more](https://veenstra.me.uk/2018/06/19/microsoft-flow-which-flow-ran-on-my-item/)

> `https://xxx.flow.microsoft.com/manage/environments/07aa1562-fea6-4583-8d76-9a8e67cbf298/flows/141e89fb-af2d-47ac-be25-f9176e64e9a0/runs/08586722084717816659969428791CU12?backUrl=%2Fflows%2F141e89fb-af2d-47ac-be25-f9176e64e9a0%2Fdetails&runStatus=Failed`
>
> There are 3 guids that I need to find aso that I can build up the flow history url.
>
> The first guid is my environmentName (07aa1562-fea6-4583-8d76-9a8e67cbf298), then I’ve got the flow name ( 141e89fb-af2d-47ac-be25-f9176e64e9a0) and finally the run (08586722084717816659969428791CU12).

Answer (score 0):

There is a cmdlet from Microsoft 365 CLI to resubmit a flow run

**m365 flow run resubmit --environment flowEnvironmentID --flow flowGUID --name flowRunID –confirm**

You can also resubmit a flow run using Power Automate REST API

**[https://api.flow.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.ProcessSimple/environments/{FlowEnvironment}/flows/{FlowGUID}/triggers/manual/histories/{FlowRunID}/resubmit?api-version=2016-11-01](https://api.flow.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.ProcessSimple/environments/%7BFlowEnvironment%7D/flows/%7BFlowGUID%7D/triggers/manual/histories/%7BFlowRunID%7D/resubmit?api-version=2016-11-01)**

For the Power Automate REST API, you will have to pass an authorization token.

For more information, go through the following post
https://ashiqf.com/2021/05/09/resubmit-your-failed-power-automate-flow-runs-automatically-using-m365-cli-and-rest-api/